# How to insert a row in the middle of a slowly changing dimension type 2 based on a date value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to insert a record in a SCD- 2 table. Databse we are using Oracle 12C. Situation is as below -
Current record set in SCD2 table -

```
Prod_Id Begin_Version_dt End_version_dt
'1234',  '2020-03-10',    '2020-04-09'
'1234',  '2020-04-10',    '2020-05-10'
'1234',  '2020-05-11',    '9999-12-31'
```

A record came in Prod transaction table as below -

```
Prod_Id  Trans_dt
'1234', '2020-05-15'
```

The updated record set in SCD2 should be -

```
Prod_Id Begin_Version_dt End_version_dt
'1234',  '2020-03-10',    '2020-04-09'
'1234',  '2020-04-10',    '2020-05-10'
'1234',  '2020-05-11',    '2020-05-14'  
'1234',  '2020-05-15',    '9999-12-31'
```

I have tried using LEAD and LAG function but they are not giving me extra record set.Any pointer will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two queries. First for inserting a record and then second for updating the dates as follows:

**Creating the sample data**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE yourTable AS (
  2      SELECT '1234' AS Prod_Id, date '2020-03-10' AS Begin_Version_dt, date '2020-04-09' AS End_version_dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3      SELECT '1234', date '2020-04-10', date '2020-05-10' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4      SELECT '1234', date '2020-05-11', date '9999-12-31' FROM dual
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE prod_table as
  2  (SELECT 1234 AS PROD_ID, DATE '2020-05-15' AS TRANS_DATE FROM DUAL);

Table created.
```

**Current view of data:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE ORDER BY BEGIN_VERSION_DT;

PROD BEGIN_VER END_VERSI
---- --------- ---------
1234 10-MAR-20 09-APR-20
1234 10-APR-20 10-MAY-20
1234 11-MAY-20 31-DEC-99

SQL> select * from prod_table;

   PROD_ID TRANS_DAT
---------- ---------
      1234 15-MAY-20
```

**Queries that you are looking for**

```
SQL> INSERT INTO yourTable Y
  2  SELECT PROD_ID, TRANS_DATE, TRANS_DATE FROM PROD_TABLE;

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> UPDATE YOURTABLE YY
  2     SET END_VERSION_DT = COALESCE(
  3  (SELECT LD_BEGIN_DT
  4    FROM (SELECT Y.BEGIN_VERSION_DT,
  5     Y.PROD_ID,
  6     LEAD(Y.BEGIN_VERSION_DT)
  7  OVER (PARTITION BY Y.PROD_ID
  8  ORDER BY Y.BEGIN_VERSION_DT) - 1 AS LD_BEGIN_DT
  9    FROM YOURTABLE Y) Y
 10    WHERE YY.PROD_ID = Y.PROD_ID
 11  AND YY.BEGIN_VERSION_DT = Y.BEGIN_VERSION_DT),
 12  DATE '9999-12-31');

4 rows updated.
```

**Updated data:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE ORDER BY BEGIN_VERSION_DT;
PROD BEGIN_VER END_VERSI
---- --------- ---------
1234 10-MAR-20 09-APR-20
1234 10-APR-20 10-MAY-20
1234 11-MAY-20 14-MAY-20
1234 15-MAY-20 31-DEC-99
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `LEAD` with a default value:

```
SELECT
    Prod_Id,
    Begin_Version_dt,
    COALESCE(End_Version_dt,
             LEAD(Begin_Version_dt, 1, date '9999-12-31')
             OVER (PARTITION BY Prod_Id ORDER BY Begin_Version_dt)) AS End_Version_dt
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Prod_Id,
    Begin_Version_dt;
```

### Demo

The logic here is that we select, if available, any non `NULL` end version date.  In the event that an end version date be *not* available, we look to take the lead of the next begin date in the sequence.  In the event that this, too, be not available, then we default to reporting `9999-12-31` as the end version date.